# How to map a flux with mono?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have these two requests:

```
Flux<ProductID> getProductIds() {
    return this.webClient.get()
            .uri(PRODUCT_ID_URI)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ProductID.class);
}

Mono<Product> getProduct(String id) {
    return this.itemServiceWebClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(PRODUCT_URI + "/{id}")
                    .build(id))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(Product.class));
}
```

And with these I want to do the following:

```
Flux<Product> getProducts() {
    return Flux.create(sink -> this.gateway.getProductIds()
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                log.info("PRODUCTS COMPLETE");

                sink.complete();
            })
            .flatMap(productId -> this.getProduct(productId.getID()))
            .subscribe(product -> {
                log.info("NEW PRODUCT: " + product);

                sink.next(product);
            }));
}
```

When I call this I get the following output:

```
PRODUCTS COMPLETE
NEW PRODUCT: ...
NEW PRODUCT: ...
....
```

Ofcourse the stream is closing before the results are actually there because the the async mono mapping. How can I keep this non-blocking but also making sure that the results arrive before the on complete is called?

Comment: Could you explain what your goal is? Do you want to have a `Flux<Product>` when given ids? Are you doing something specific with those ids, besides fetching the product information? I don't understand why you've chosen to use Flux.create in this case.

Comment: What else schould I do? The code where I call `getProducts()` is perofrming `.toStream()` because of that I cant do a `.subscribe()` there. My goal is to have a fully reactive chain from getting the ids over getting the product for each id to setting the products in my view when the stream is completed.

Comment: In your view? So this is a controller method?

Comment: Yes - `getProducts()` is a controller method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `getProducts` is a controller method and that you want to add those products in your model to be rendered in a view template, you could solve this problem like this:

```
@GetMapping("/products")
public String getProducts(Model model) {

    Flux<Product> products = this.gateway.getProductIds()
            .flatMap(productId -> this.getProduct(productId.getID()));
    model.put("products", products);
    // return the view name
    return "showProducts";
}
```